# Can an account's transactions be front-run on Polkadot? If so, how?

Tags: transactions, polkadot-js

Is it possible to reliably monitor an account and receive information about a transaction of that account *before* the transaction is `InBlock` and then front-run that transaction by issuing a sufficiently larger tip? If so, how would one do this using polkadot-js?

Expanding this, the interesting problem is how to obtain the information about transactions considered for inclusion in a block. When this information is available, the transaction can be front-run by making sure that your transaction has higher priority using a sufficiently large tip (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70734079/is-polkadot-transaction-priority-only-based-on-fees/70740762#70740762)). Can this information be obtained using polkadot-js?

Note: This is a problem on EVM-style networks due to the way that transactions are handled there.

Answer (score 7):

The answer in general is yes, Substrate and Polkadot use a transaction queue just like most other blockchains, and because of this it is possible to increase the transaction fees included with some transaction to give it a higher priority in the queue than another transaction.

The order of transaction in the transaction queue is managed by a transaction's "priority", and each chain may have some custom logic which is used to calculate that priority.

In Polkadot, the easiest way to manipulate the transaction priority is to include a block author `tip`: https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-transaction-fees

Your second question "If so, how would one do this using polkadot-js?"...

Well probably I would not be making such a bot in Polkadot JS, since you would be unlikely to actually front-run any transactions with such a program. Instead, you probably need to build this logic into a custom Substrate / Polkadot client which itself is a block producer, and manipulates the transactions you are including in a block.

However, if you want to learn how to increase the priority of your transaction using a tip in Polkadot JS, here is a [snippet](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/examples/promise/make-transfer):

```
const hash = await extrinsic.signAndSend(alice, { tip: amount });
```

Comment: "Instead, you probably need to build this logic into a custom Substrate / Polkadot client which itself is a block producer, and manipulates the transactions you are including in a block." - This is because only the block producers receive the info of which transactions are candidates for inclusion in a block? This info cannot be obtained using polkadot-js?

Comment: The main reason here I think it is that block producer has access to the transaction pool.